# LinearLayout wrap_content of a Cardslib card

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Using https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib, I want a layout that looks like the following:

```
----------- (this card has dynamic text 
|this is  |  and its height should adjust
|a card   |  to the amount of text automatically)
-----------
=========== (separator)
-----------
|this is  |
|a        |
|CardsList|
-----------
```

Here's what I have right now:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/wrapper">

        <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ddd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/match_ongoing_hand"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is the LinearLayout takes up the entire screen, even if there is only a small amount of text in the top card. If I set the LinearLayout to a specific layout_height, I can see the CardListView. In CardListView, cards naturally wrap to their text. I'd like the LinearLayout to wrap to the top card's height. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: try wrap_content for the LinearLayout child , but i think setting match_parent for CardListView will cause a problem unless you define a layout_below for that.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. And I can't define a layout_below for CardListView because that causes a circular dependency error. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I think this layout should do what you want:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ddd"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/match_ongoing_hand" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I think you can safely remove the `layout_alignParentLeft` and `layout_alignParentStart` attributes from the divider `View`.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. Still the same issue with the CardView taking up the entire screen. Why did you make CardListView's layout_height 0dp?

Comment: With its weight set to 1, it'll cause it to take up the space not occupied by the other Views. At least with normal Views.

Comment: I understand. Anyway, I was able to get this to work by changing my top CardView to a CardListView and just putting the one Card inside of the list. A hack, but it works. Maybe this has something to do with Cardslib's Card layout.